A required field, when out of view from the screen, is focused when it is not filled, but it doesn't show the message from html5
When the field is visible like the image below:
Field visible
The messages appears when I submit the form.
But if the field is not visible like the image below:
Field not visible
The message does not appears.
The main problem is that although I could tune down a bit the padding and such, I would like to understand if this behavior is the default one, and if there is a way of changing it?

In what environment, and can you reproduce it with a [mre] and include the code in your question? Works for me on Chrome 131.0.6778.86 on macOS, for one.

@Ry- i'm not sure what you're asking for. I use flask for the rendering of the template, then plain simple html5. My browser is https://brave.com/latest/ and I'm on windows.
the code is a bit long, i put it in github. Mind the things from jinja like the {block} and stuff, but in a html online editor i tried it and my problem happens
https://github.com/Damian-Bicocchi/test/blob/main/form.html

I also tried it in Chrome Versión 131.0.6778.86 in Windows and it doesn't work also

Do you want to remove the message but have it focused when left blank? If so, it isn't possible without scripting.
